# Select tables list based on a where condition in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Please help to find the table list based on a where condition. I am able to get table list in Snowflake using below query :

```
   select table_name 
   from information_schema.tables 
   where table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
   and table_name like UPPER('DIM_STUDENT_NAME%');
```

All these tables have a timestamp column and my requirement is to find the list of tables where that timestamp column is less than 30days. Appreciate if someone can help me here.

Comment: You would need to write dynamic SQL to loop through the list of tables, create and execute the query for each table and process the result. You could do this in a Stored Procedure or, probably, an anonymous block

Answer (score 1):

try add condition :

```
select table_name 
   from information_schema.tables 
   where table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
   and table_name like UPPER('DIM_STUDENT_NAME%') and 
datediff(day, TableField,current_date() ) <= 30
```